Migrating azure function from v3 to v4
Trying to migrate from v3 to v4
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-typescript using this documenttaion
I want to modify below code to v4
In v3
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"

const cgHttpTrigger: AzureFunction = async (
  context: any,
  req: any,
  httpTrigger: AzureFunction
) => {
  return appInsights.wContext(async () => {
    const startTime = Date.now() // Start trackRequest timer

    // Run the Function
    await httpTrigger(context, req)

    // Track Request on completion
    a.d.trackRequest({
      name: context.req.method + " " + context.req.url,
      resultCode: context.res.status,
  }, correlationContext ?? undefined)()
}

I was trying to use app from v4 azure/functions and trying to wrap above function
In v4
import { app} from '@azure/functions';

    app.http('appIn', {
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      handler: cgHttpTrigger(httpTrigger),
    });

how can i wrap this to something like
handler:  async (req, context) => {return cgHttpTrigger(req, context, (req, context) => {....})} 

Resources
https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights/v/2.0.0-beta.200831.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-typescript using this documenttaion

It looks like package applicationinsights works in v3 function due to presence of Context in @azure/functions but v4 model has InvocationContext. So I believe, it is correctly works with v3 model only

I want to migrate it to v4 how can i do that @IkhtesamAfrin

why do you want to use applicationinsights package? Do you have any specific requirement or you just want to use handler:  async (req, context) => {return cgHttpTrigger(req, context, (req, context) => {....})}  format in v4?

@IkhtesamAfrin as the code is implemented in this form only and I can only migrate ,so i have to use both  (applicationinsights  and handler from app )as we are tracking requests

also as you said applicationinsights works in v3 function due to presence of Context in @azure/functions cant we use InvocationContext from v4 to replace it ?
@IkhtesamAfrin

without using applicationinsights package also, you can track the request in app insight. You need to use the instance of InvocationContext and then log the data either as per your need like context.log(), context.info, context.trace or context.error. In order to see these logs, you need to deploy the function to function app

I believe the method startOperation of applicationinsights has a dependency on azureFunctionsTypes.Context

in RECENT EDIT , I have added original code to show why i need appinsight @IkhtesamAfrin

Refer to this github issue https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/1299#issuecomment-2123651145, it says that applicationinsights package only supports v3 for now and support for v4 is under development

So what can I do right now the best possible way to accomodate this migration
@IkhtesamAfrin

You need to consider using any other package like @azure/monitor-opentelemetry

can we avoid using that and still include the wrapper of the insights on the handler function to accomodate this ?@IkhtesamAfrin

But in that case also we need to pass context parameter at some point, then it throw @azure/functions/types/index"' has no exported member 'Context'. error

As suggested we have to switch to @azure/monitor-opentelemetry
Reason -
Refer to this github issue github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/issues/…, it says that applicationinsights package only supports v3 for now and support for v4 is under development.
